# md-spinner stopped working in angular2 material alpha.10

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I had md-spinner working with angular2-material alpha.8-2.  I installed @angular/material alpha.10, and updated my imports:

**Before**

```
import { MdCardModule } from '@angular2-material/card';
import { MdToolbarModule } from '@angular2-material/toolbar';
import { MdProgressCircleModule } from '@angular2-material/progress-circle';
```

**After**

```
import { MdCardModule, MdToolbarModule, MdProgressCircleModule } from '@angular/material';
```

But my md-spinner progress circles have gone invisible. If I inspect one in Chrome, I see a blank svg spinning, but nothing drawn/rendered. Reverting to md-progress-circle also doesn't help.

```
<md-spinner></md-spinner>
<md-progress-circle mode="indeterminate"></md-progress-circle>
```

Is there something else I need to do to get the md-spinner working?

Answer (score 2):

In your index.html add angular materal stylesheets

```
<link href="node_modules/@angular/material/core/theming/prebuilt/indigo-pink.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

working md-spinner [here](https://material.angular.io/components/component/progress-spinner)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but this worked for me.
This is a shorter way for importing material modules. Instead of importing one at a time:

```
import { MaterialModule } from '@angular/material';
```

Before:

```
<md-progress-spinner><md-spinner mode="indeterminate"></md-spinner></md-progress-spinner>
```

After:

```
<md-spinner mode="indeterminate"></md-spinner>
```

Comment: There is no "MaterialModule" exported after 2.0.0-beta.11 version of angular material